# Getting Exit Code 127 (Command not Found) from php exec()

Tags: php

EDIT - Adding new info at the top for visibility. The www-data user can't use the `exec()` command. All attempts return a 127 error.

I setup a simple script that is just this

```
<?php
$res = exec("echo EXEC", $res1, $res2);
var_dump($res);
var_dump($res1);
var_dump($res2);
?>
```

When executed via the application (which of course runs as www-data) this returns the 127 error code.
When executed via this command it runs flawlessly `sudo -u root php testExec.php`
When executed via this command it again returns the 127 error code `sudo -u www-data php testExec.php`

> Original Question

I can only seem to get the error code 127 back when trying to use the `exec` command in php. I'm trying to use the https://github.com/rialto-php/puphpeteer package to generate pdfs and it was working flawlessly but I can't find what changed that is causing it to fail now.

I've been using `/usr/local/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/bin/node` as the path to node but I also tried copying it here `/node/v16.14.2/bin` so I could give the entire directory structure execute permissions. In either/both places node is owned by www-data (the user that php runs as) and has execute permissions (755).

Running `'/node/v16.14.2/bin/node' '/var/www/html/vendor/nesk/puphpeteer/src/get-puppeteer-version.js'` (the initial command that puphpeteer generates) from the command line works just fine and returns the expected result `"5.5.0"` so node is there and executable and the get-puppeteer-version script exists.

After troubleshooting that I decided to just test exec and discovered that that doesn't work for any commands. I've tried just running `exec("date");` and `exec("echo EXEC")` and these also return the same exit code 127.

The disable_functions ini setting is empty (confirmed via empty result from `ini_get('disable_functions')`). Safe mode is not enabled (confirmed via false result from `ini_get('safe_mode')`).

If anyone has any insight into why exec won't work at all would be great!

Environment:
Ubuntu 18.04.4
PHP 8.1

Comment: This lacks lots of details, like configuration file and other related software versions. Please extract a [mcve] and provide that in your question.

Comment: What other software versions are relevant here? What configurations would you like more insight into? I'm sure there is something specific on my system that is the source of the issue so reproducing it elsewhere is unlikely. 
I'm hoping for any insight into what else may cause the exec command to fail so I can investigate further there.

Comment: With PHP, the question is always which way you're invoking the scripts. From the CLI or one of multiple webservers? In any case, you can use `strace` to get the actual error code from the PHP invocation. The point of the [mcve] is also to strip distractions (provided they are distractions!) like puphpeteer, NVM/Node etc. BTW: Check which shell is configured for the www-data user, that could have an influence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after further investigation.. I found that this was indeed a permissions issue. I had double checked that node and everything in the /bin folder had appropriate execute permissions..

What I had missed (and am not sure how it got changed) was that the /bin folder itself didn't have the appropriate execute permissions. Adding those immediately fixed my issue.